# After shutting down laptop from ubuntu 16.04 it getting hot

Tags: drivers, 16.04, kernel

I am new to ubuntu 16.04. It is dual booted with windows 10.
After installing ubuntu 16.04 i fetch a problem that if i shut down my laptop from ubuntu it getting hot though it is shut down.Now i am helpless and need help to solve this problem. How to fix this problem?
My laptop model is HP pavilion 15-AB203Tx

Comment: How are you shutting off your laptop? It can be configured to keep running when the lid is closed.

Comment: Like @WinEunuuchs2Unix said, how are you shutting down your computer? Are you waiting for it to completely shut down (no lights, no fan, etc.), or are you simply closing the lid and calling it "shut down"? If it is truly shut down there should be almost no current running. I would be very worried if my laptop was heating up when shut down- this might be a sign of battery failure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first test that the suspend functionality works without closing the lid

```
systemctl suspend
```

you should see the system suspend , it should wake up when you press a key or move the mouse.

then try hibernating without closing the lid

```
systemctl hibernate
```

If both of those work and your laptop isn't getting hot then it would seem like the lid sensor is either faulty or not being setup properly.

If either of these don't work then it would seem your problem is that its not actually suspending or hibernating when you close the lid, maybe you have some services running that won't suspend, an external monitor or an experimental hardware driver.

Work your way through this guide if its not suspending or hibernating 
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingKernelSuspend

Comment: Kira said they "shut it down" and we still don't know what they meant by that 2 hours after seeking clarification.